# How to get time from dynamic time zone using moment.js

Tags: php, jquery, timezone, momentjs

I want to get user local time from his timezone. For this i am using following code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                var tz = jstz.determine(); // Determines the time zone of the browser client      
                var timestamp = '<?php echo $value->created_at->sec; ?>';        
                var localtime = moment.unix(timestamp).utcOffset(tz).format('MM/DD/YY hh:mm');  
                console.log(timestamp+"==>"+tz.name()+'==>'+localtime);        

            });        

            </script>
```

I got accurate timezone from this code but did not able to get actual time from current timezone.
I have included moment.js and jstz.js in my code already.
How can i get the user local time ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to actually know what the time zone identifier is to work in the local time zone, so there's no need to use jsTimeZoneDetect (aka `jstz`).

Since local time is the default, you can just do:

```
moment.unix(timestamp).format('MM/DD/YY hh:mm')
```